# React - changing from react.createClass to component class Key issue

Tags: reactjs

I decided to pick up on learning some react and spring boot.
I followed this tutorial link: https://stormpath.com/blog/crud-application-react-spring-boot-user-authentication

I was able to get the application working following the tutorial but I relized that it is outdated and now i think the preferred way to create classes is though components and not using createclass(). So i tried to change it to use components insted.

I get this warning on the EmployeeTable class / compnent: 
Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `EmployeeTable`.

This is what my EmployeeTable looks like after changing it to a component. I am not sure how to add keys into the component yet or if i need to add key inside employee as well. Help to understand how to change this createclass function to a component would help me understand more about react.js.

If you need further information please let me know! 
Below is my js file:

```
class Employee extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state.display = true;
    }

    handleDelete() {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: self.props.employee._links.self.href,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(result) {
                self.setState({display: false});
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                toastr.error(xhr.responseJSON.message);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.display==false){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return (
                <tr key={this.props.employee.Gmid.toString()}>
                    <td>{this.props.employee.Gmid}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.employee.name}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.employee.age}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.employee.years}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>)
        }

    }
}

class EmployeeTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        var rows = [];
        this.props.employees.forEach(function (employee) {
            rows.push(React.createElement(Employee, { employee: employee }));
        });
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gmid</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Years</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>)
    }
}

var addNewUserButton = <button class="btn btn-default" onClick="showNewUserCreatinonForm"> Add New User </button>

function AddUserButton(props){
    return(
        <button class="btn btn-default" onClick="showNewUserCreatinonForm"> Add New User </button>
)
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       this.state = { employees: []};
    }

    loadEmployeesFromServer() {
        var self = this;
        var host = window.location.hostname;
        var urlHost = "";
        if(host == "localhost"){
            urlHost="http://localhost:8008/davidsAwesomeReactApplication/api/employees"
        }
        else{
            urlHost="https://"+host+"/davidsAwesomeReactApplication/api/employees"
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: urlHost
        }).then(function (data) {
            self.setState({employees: data._embedded.employees});
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadEmployeesFromServer()
    }

    render() {
        return ( <EmployeeTable employees={this.state.employees}/> );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var rows = [];
this.props.employees.forEach(function (employee) {
    rows.push(React.createElement(Employee, { employee: employee }));
});
```

with

```
var rows = this.props.employees.map(function (employee) {
    return (
      <Employee employee={employee}>
    );
});
```

You can just map each employee object to an `<Employee />` component. The call to `React.createElement()` can be replaced with JSX. It is the same thing. The latter is syntactic sugar to the former and is better to visualize.

Now, whenever you work with arrays in React and you map from an object to a component, it requires you define a key prop on each component. So simply do the following:

```
<Employee key={employee.id} employee={employee}>
```

The key prop should be a unique identifier, so assuming your employee object has an `id`, that should be the way go.

Comment: Thank you! Dumb Question, where do I put that code snippet?<Employee key={employee.id} employee={employee}> I am not sure where this key/employee would go. I am returning rows, but I'm not sure how to tie in the key in that return.

Comment: It goes in the return value of the function that is passed to map. It replaces what I wrote previously. You need only add `key={employee.id}`